# PG_TOAST tables are creating with AccessExclusiveLock for Temp tables while executing a Postgres Transaction

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, database-administration

In one of my Postgres Transaction (executing a procedure), I'm using more than 50 temp tables and for each temp table it is creating pg_toast_temptableOID, pg_toast_temptableOID_index with AccessExclusiveLock and fastpath = false for these pg_toast tables. It is creating slowness in my procedure execution. Please let me know how to improve the Performance.

Note: I'm using temp tables because the incoming data is huge and CTEs will make it very slow.

Comment: How did you determine that the slowness has anything to do with the locks?

Answer (score 1):

- Try to reduce the number of temp tables.
- Use Optimized Queries
- Use `VACUUM` and `ANALYZE` for further optimization of database.
- Avoiding the use of unnecessary indexes.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some methods which might solve your problem.

- Reduce the number of temporary tables and try to use Common table expressions (CTEs).
- Try to use **Access_Exclusive_Lock** only when required.
- Try to use database connection pooling.
- Analyze the performance of queries by `EXPLAIN`.